# How to make screen from tabBarNavigator invisible on TabBar?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I use react-navigation version 3.x. How to make screen from tabBarNavigator invisible on TabBar?

I need to remove main screen from tabBar(it should be invisible) but TabBar must be on main screen.

My screen structure is next:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    loginFlow: { 
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        intro: { screen: Intro },
        login: { screen: Login },
        registration: { screen: Registration }
      })
    },
    mainFlow: {
      screen: createStackNavigator({

        // settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
        someTab: { 
          screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
            main: { screen: Home },
            Tab1: { screen: Tab1 },
            Tab2: { screen: Tab2 },
            Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
            Tab4: { screen: ChatMain }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your question is contradicting itself. You want to remove main screen from tabBar(it should be invisible) but TabBar must be on main screen? What exactly is that you are expecting to do? Please attach screenshots if it helps you explain better.

Comment: main screeen must have tabBar but on babBar must be visible only 4 icons and title for Tab1-Tab4

Comment: How did you get on with the help rendered below, Hannibal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just used my own TabBar component. just need to use `tabBarComponent` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is worded weirdly, but I'll give you answers to both of my interpretations:

If you want so remove a screen from your tab bar, simply comment it out:

```
// main: { screen: Home },
```

If you want to have the main screen in the same stack as the rest of your tab bar, but not want it to show within the tab bar, you could nest it inside a `switchNavigator`:

```
mainFlow: {
  screen: createStackNavigator({
    // settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    someSwitch: createSwitchNavigator({
      main: { screen: Home },
      someTab: { 
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
          Tab1: { screen: Tab1 },
          Tab2: { screen: Tab2 },
          Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
          Tab4: { screen: ChatMain }
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```